# How to reliably force virtual dispatch on an object's method?

Tags: c++, state-machine, fsm

## Context

I have a FSM in which every state is represented as a class. All states derive from a common base class and have one virtual function for handling input.

As only one state can be active at a time all possible states are stored in a union inside the FSM's class.

## The problem

As all states (including the base class) are stored by value, I can't use virtual dispath directly. Instead I create a reference to the base object in the union using static_cast and then call the virtual method through that reference. This works on GCC. It doesn't work on Clang.

Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct State {
    virtual std::string do_the_thing();
    virtual ~State() {}
};

struct IdleState: State {
    std::string do_the_thing() override;
};

std::string State::do_the_thing() {
    return "State::do_the_thing() is called";
}

std::string IdleState::do_the_thing() {
    return "IdleState::do_the_thing() is called";
}

int main() {
    union U {
        U() : idle_state() {}
        ~U() { idle_state.~IdleState(); }
        State state;
        IdleState idle_state;
    } mem;

    std::cout
        << "By reference: "
        << static_cast<State&>(mem.state).do_the_thing()
        << "\n";

    std::cout
        << "By pointer:   "
        << static_cast<State*>(&mem.state)->do_the_thing()
        << "\n";
}
```

When I compile this code with GCC 8.2.1 the output of the program is:

```sh
By reference: IdleState::do_the_thing() is called
By pointer:   State::do_the_thing() is called
```

When I compile it with Clang 8.0.0 the output is:

```sh
By reference: State::do_the_thing() is called
By pointer:   IdleState::do_the_thing() is called
```

So the behaviour of the two compilers is inverted: GCC performs virtual dispatch only through a reference, Clang only through a pointer.

One solution I have found is to use `reinterpret_cast<State&>(mem)` (so a cast from the union itself to a `State&`). This works on both compilers, bit I am still unsure how portable this is. And the reason I put the base class in the union was to specifically avoid a reinterpret_cast in the first place...

So what is the proper way of forcing virtual dispatch in such cases?

**Update**

To summarize, one way of doing this is having a separate pointer of the base class' type outside the union (or std::variant), which points to the current active member.

Directly accessing a subclass in the union as if it were the base class is not safe.

Comment: "*I create a reference to the base object in the union*" - but you are not doing that, instead you are storing an instance of `State` object and an instance of `IdleState` objects and then cast inactive field `state` to the type of active field which causes Undefined Behavior. Is there anything preventing you from using virtual dispath directly? Note that it would work if you have actually stored a reference somewhere

Comment: @VTT, well, all members of the union are subclasses of `State`, which means no matter what member of the union is active, I can still use the field `state`. It is `static_cast`able to anything in the union. Your suggestion of storing the reference first actually seems to work! Although I completely don't understand why... I am trying it now.

Comment: *"all members of the union are subclasses of State, which means no matter what member of the union is active, I can still use the field state"* - unfortunately not, it is only possible to access common initial sequence of fields of standard layout types. Types that have virtual functions are not standard layout types therefore you get Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @VTT And a base object isn't a common initial sequence anyway.

Comment: Ah, so I guess it was working by coincidence. In this simple case they had the same binary layout in GCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access the inactive member of a union. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> all members of the union are subclasses of State, which means no matter what member of the union is active, I can still use the field `state`

It does not mean that.

A solution is to store a pointer to the base object separately. Furthermore, you'll need to keep track of which union state is currently active. This is simplest to solve using variant class:

```
class U {
public:
    U() {
        set<IdleState>();
    }

    // copy and move functions left as an exercise
    U(const U&) = delete;
    U& operator=(const U&) = delete;

    State& get() { return *active_state; }

    template<class T>
    void set() {
        storage = T{};
        active_state = &std::get<T>(storage);
    }
private:
    State* active_state;
    std::variant<IdleState, State> storage;
};

// usage
U mem;
std::cout << mem.get().do_the_thing();
```

Comment: Wait, this is beautiful. And here I was messing with unions, placement new and manual destructors... std::variant is so much better. I completely ignored it before.

Comment: @ea7ababe placement new is what variant does under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Use of

```
std::cout
    << "By reference: "
    << static_cast<State&>(mem.state).do_the_thing()
    << "\n";
```

is wrong. It causes undefined behavior since `mem.state` has not been initialized and is not the active member of `mem`.

---

I suggest a change of strategy.

1. Don't use a `union`.
2. Use a regular `class`/`struct` that holds a smart pointer. It can point to an insance of any sub-type of `State`.
3. Make `State` an abstract base class to disallow its instantiation.

```
class State {
    public:
       virtual std::string do_the_thing() = 0;

    protected:
       State() {}
       virtual ~State() = 0 {}
};

// ...
// More code from your post
// ...

struct StateHolder
{
   std::unique_ptr<State> theState; // Can be a shared_ptr too.
};


int main()
{
    StateHolder sh;
    sh.theState = new IdleState;

    std::cout << sh.theState->do_the_thing() << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is what my class originally looked like, but doing it through pointers means allocations and deallocations on every state change. I was really hoping I could make it work by just reusing one memory location.

Comment: @ea7ababe, if that's a concern, you can keep a map of various states and and the key to the active state.

Answer (score 0):

So, eerorika's answer has inspired me to the following solution. It is a bit closer to what I had originally (no separate pointer to union members), but I have delegated all the dirty work to std::variant (instead of a union).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <utility>

// variant_cb is a std::variant with a
// common base class for all variants.
template<typename Interface, typename... Variants>
class variant_cb {
    static_assert(
        (sizeof...(Variants) > 0),
        "At least one variant expected, got zero.");

    static_assert(
        (std::is_base_of<Interface, Variants>::value && ...),
        "All members of variant_cb must have the same base class "
        "(the first template parameter).");

public:
    variant_cb() = default;

    template<typename T>
    variant_cb(T v) : v(v) {}

    variant_cb(const variant_cb&) = default;
    variant_cb(variant_cb&&) = default;
    variant_cb& operator=(const variant_cb&) = default;
    variant_cb& operator=(variant_cb&&) = default;

    Interface& get() {
        return std::visit([](Interface& x) -> Interface& {
            return x;
        }, v);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Interface& set() {
        v = T{};
        return std::get<T>(v);
    }

private:
    std::variant<Variants...> v;
};

// Usage:

class FSM {
public:
    enum Input { DO_THE_THING, /* ... */ };

    void handle_input(Input input) {
        auto& state = current_state.get();
        current_state = state(input);
    }

private:
    struct State;
    struct Idle;
    struct Active;

    using AnyState = variant_cb<State, Idle, Active>;

    template<typename T>
    static AnyState next_state() {
        return {std::in_place_type<T>};
    }

    struct State {
        virtual ~State() {};
        virtual AnyState operator()(Input) = 0;
    };

    struct Idle: State {
        AnyState operator()(Input) override {
            std::cout << "Idle -> Active\n";
            return next_state<Active>();
        }
    };

    struct Active: State {
        int countdown = 3;

        AnyState operator()(Input) override {
            if (countdown > 0) {
                std::cout << countdown << "\n";
                countdown--;
                return *this;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Active -> Idle\n";
                return next_state<Idle>();
            }
        }
    };

    AnyState current_state;
};

int main() {
    FSM fsm;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fsm.handle_input(FSM::DO_THE_THING);
    }

    // Output:
    //
    // Idle -> Active
    // 3
    // 2
    // 1
    // Active -> Idle
}
```